# How to deal with mini-batch loss in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, loss

I feed mini-batch data to model, and I just want to know how to deal with the loss. Could I accumulate the loss, then call the backward like:

```
    ...
    def neg_log_likelihood(self, sentences, tags, length):
        self.batch_size = sentences.size(0)

        logits = self.__get_lstm_features(sentences, length)
        real_path_score = torch.zeros(1)
        total_score = torch.zeros(1)
        if USE_GPU:
            real_path_score = real_path_score.cuda()
            total_score = total_score.cuda()

        for logit, tag, leng in zip(logits, tags, length):
            logit = logit[:leng]
            tag = tag[:leng]
            real_path_score += self.real_path_score(logit, tag)
            total_score += self.total_score(logit, tag)
        return total_score - real_path_score
    ...
loss = model.neg_log_likelihood(sentences, tags, length)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

I wonder that if the accumulation could lead to gradient explosion?

So, should I call the backward in loop:

```
for sentence, tag , leng in zip(sentences, tags, length):
    loss = model.neg_log_likelihood(sentence, tag, leng)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Or, use the mean loss just like the **reduce_mean** in tensorflow

```
loss = reduce_mean(losses)
loss.backward()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `loss` has to be reduced by `mean` using the mini-batch size. If you look at the native PyTorch loss functions such as [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=cross_entropy#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss), there is a separate parameter `reduction` just for this and the default behaviour is to do `mean` on the mini-batch size.

Answer (score 1):

We usually

1. get the loss by the loss function
2. (if necessary) manipulate the loss, for example do the class weighting and etc
3. calculate the mean loss of the mini-batch
4. calculate the gradients by the `loss.backward()`
5. (if necessary) manipulate the gradients, for example, do the gradient clipping for some RNN models to avoid gradient explosion
6. update the weights using the `optimizer.step()` function

So in your case, you can first get the mean loss of the mini-batch and then calculate the gradient using the `loss.backward()` function and then utilize the `optimizer.step()` function for the weight updating.